# Is there a way to use Google Colab Form feature in a local Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have just installed a Jupyter Notebook in a local `conda` environment, and I've imported an `.ipynb` file from Google Colab to run it locally.

I wonder if there's any extension that enables the Form feature from Google Colab to work on a regular Jupyter Notebook, using the same syntax, like this below: [image]

PS: I'm aware of the Jupyter Widgets (`ipywidgets`) package/extension, however the syntax is different from Colab Forms, ideally I would want to keep the same syntax so I could use the same file back and forth between Colab and local easily

Comment: Looks like there's nothing that uses that **exact** syntax (or at least, that I could find). You might want to look into making your own library.

Comment: ipywidgets do work on Colab too.

Comment: I adress that on the `PS:` in the question. ipywidgets require you running the cell, while the colab form syntax does not - between many other reasons (colab users enjoy using the form, etc. etc.)

Answer (score 11):

***Disclaimer: this is not a strict solution to the problem presented by the OP, but it is a viable alternative.***

For months I have been looking for a way to have certain Google Colab functionality locally, but to no avail. In particular, to date I haven't found a way to:

1. Run Google Colab locally (offline).
2. Have the functionalities of Google Colab forms locally (offline) using the same syntax.

However, since one of the main motivations for using Jupyter locally is to use the computational resources of the local machine, Google Colab offers a very simple way to take advantage of all the features of the platform using a local Jupyter environment:

1. Upload your notebook to Google Drive and open it with Google Colab.
2. Click the arrow next to the "Connect" button and then click "Connect to a local runtime".

[image]

3. Follow the instructions.

[image]

Then you can use the same file back and forth between Google Colab and your local environment easily.

[image: Result]

Comment: Nice solution... I tried disconnecting from the internet after connecting to the local runtime, but when evaluating code blocks it complained it needed to download some JS code in order to emit the output... Who knows, probably after a first complete run it won't need internet access anymore?