# Is there a way to show Google colab forms in jupyter notebooks?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I came across [colab forms](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/forms.ipynb#scrollTo=3jKM6GfzlgpS) in a notebook is there a way to render them as forms in jupyter notebooks?

For example:

```py
#@title String fields

text = 'value' #@param {type:"string"}
dropdown = '1st option' #@param ["1st option", "2nd option", "3rd option"]
text_and_dropdown = 'value' #@param ["1st option", "2nd option", "3rd option"] {allow-input: true}

print(text)
print(dropdown)
print(text_and_dropdown)
```

Would be rendered like this in colab:

[image]

Comment: Google Colab is a highly customized branch of **old** Jupyter tech. The forms were one of the big customizations. You can get a lot of the same functionality using [ipywidgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html) in current Jupyter ecosystem. Also see comments in reply to ['Is there a way to use Google Colab Form feature in a local Jupyter Notebook?'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68360285/8508004)

Answer (score 0):

Google Colab offers a very simple way to take advantage of all the features of the platform using a local Jupyter environment:

Upload your notebook to Google Drive and open it with Google Colab.
Click the arrow next to the "Connect" button and then click "Connect to a local runtime".

This answer is a snippet from the very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71419040/4755832